# Image not showing in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I have used the camera to save a photo to the externalDataDirectory and it appears in the cache folder. I then moved it to a sub folder of externalDataDirectory called people.

The image isn't showing in the img tag which is ... `<img src="file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.myapp/files/people/JP_Joe_Public.jpg">`

Why does my img tag not show the imag?

Comment: Are you running with --livereload?

Comment: No. Solved by using a base64 image i view :)

Comment: I see.  For reference, the normal file tag should work for Android, and for iOS you may need to adjust the source if using the normal ionic webview.  That is explained here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/.  It may be worth trying that if you don't want to spend the processing time calculating the base64 version.